# Bash Script- How to compare two files and print out the missing data

Tags: bash, shell, grep

Right now I need to create a bash script that would print out the missing sequence and the filename that is missing by comparing two files. 
 
 For example, I have a File A that contains items below 
ABC12.001 
ABC12.002 
ABC12.004 
ABC12.006 
ABC12.007 
Another File called File B containing items below 
 
ABC12.001 
ABC12.002 
ABC12.004 
ABC12.006 
I want to have an output that would print something like 
 "Sequence ABC.007 is missing from File B" 
 How should I approach this? I'd like to provide some of the codings that I tried but so far I wasn't able to produce anything useful.

Comment: `diff file_a file_b` or `comm -3 file_a file_b`?

Answer (score 0):

like this ?

```
line_a=`wc -l A|awk '{print $1}'`;line_b=`wc -l B|awk '{print $1}'`;sum_line=`expr $line_a + $line_b`;grep -qvf B A && grep -vf B A|xargs -n $sum_line|awk '{print "Sequence "$0" is missing from File B"}';grep -qvf A B && grep -vf A B|xargs -n $sum_line|awk '{print "Sequence "$0" is missing from File A"}'
```

or use the bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
A=$1
B=$2
line_a=$(grep -c ^ $A)
line_b=$(grep -c ^ $B)
sum_line=`expr $line_a + $line_b`
grep -qvf $B $A && grep -vf $B $A|xargs -n $sum_line|awk -v vB="$B" '{print "Sequence "$0" is missing from File "vB}'
grep -qvf $A $B && grep -vf $A $B|xargs -n $sum_line|awk -v vA="$A" '{print "Sequence "$0" is missing from File "vA}'
```

[image]

Comment: This assumes that each line is unique and that order is unimportant, which means you could reduce this to just `sort + comm` or even `sort | uniq`

Comment: This suggested solution was down voted - - shame reasons are not required.  I would suggest a slight performance enhancer - replace wc -l   $(grep -c ^ A ...